# How do I change the name of the key in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I've seen many posts answering this question in various forms, but somehow none seem to quite solve my problem.

PHP 5.5.8 + CodeIgniter

The complete picture:

A SQL query produces an array of department names.

```
$strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT DepartmentName FROM ...
$query=$this->db->query($strSQL);
$data=$query->result_array();
```

I flatten the array to make it really simple.

```
$flatArray = array_column($data, 'DepartmentName');
array_unshift($flatArray, "");
return $flatArray;
```

And then return in to my controller to create the drop downbox on the form.

The array however is of the form:

```
[PGroups] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Dept 1
                        [1] => Dept 2
                        [2] => Dept 3
                         .....
```

And in my (CodeIgniter based) view, I have this:

```
`echo "<td>" .  form_dropdown('PurchasingGroup', $PGroups). "</td>";`
```

which creates the HTML dropdown list with numerical values as the options, and not the actual words of the department titles.

I'm trying to get this result:

```
["Dept 1"] => Dept 1
["Dept 2"] => Dept 2
["Dept 3"] => Dept 3
.....
```

..because then when I buyild my view, the value options will be the exact text to put into my SQL search to retrieve further info.

To solve this I've tried

- doing something in the SQL statement, but that can't influence the key names - dead end
- then one post said to try this, but I don't understand how that changes the *key* name, it seems to just change the value of the element.

  $arr[$newkey] = $arr[$oldkey];
  unset($arr[$oldkey]);

It's staring me in the face, but I'm going round in circles. Help?

Comment: `$arr[$newkey] = $arr[$oldkey];` copies the contents of `$arr[$oldkey]` to another array element with key `$newkey`. In your case though, it should be `$arr[$arr[$oldkey]] = $arr[$oldkey]` because you'd like the key and value to be the same.

Comment: The answer itself is simple: `$arr = array_combine( $arr, $arr );` But I don't understand if you want modify only `$flatArray` or even original `$data`

Comment: My desired end result is a flat array where the key names and the key values are exactly the same. By whatever means.

Comment: @fusion3k - Thank you... that is exactly what I was looking for. How do I mark this as "The Answer"?

Comment: @Maxcot using the green check image

Comment: haha, I know, but I didn't see your "Answer." IT would be nice if there was a way to mark a comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace old array values you have to perform a very simple command:

```
$arr = array_combine( $arr, $arr );
print_r( $arr );
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [Dept 1] => Dept 1
    [Dept 2] => Dept 2
    [Dept 3] => Dept 3
)
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/tIgj0)**</kbd>

---

- See more about [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($PGroups as $key=>$value) $x[$value] = $value;
echo "<td>" .  form_dropdown('PurchasingGroup', $x). "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
            $tmp = Array
                (
                    [0] => 'Dept 1',
                    [1] => 'Dept 2',
                    [2] => 'Dept 3'
                );
            foreach($tmp as $i => $val)
            {
                $tmp['Dept '.($i+1)] = $val;
                unset($tmp[$i]);
            }
```